# Trying to add a submit button to a quiz

Tags: jquery, button, submit

I adopted this quiz from [here](https://codepen.io/jannypie/pen/DcHdo?editors=101) some time ago, and it works well except there has been a request for the addition of a submit button instead of the quiz advancing when you click on the answer.

I tried calling the updteStep() function via a Submit button (after removing it from the check() function, and it just doesn't respond. I have tried calling it via and onClick, and by adding an EventListener. I am not sure where to go from here.

You can see the currently working example without the submit button here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nkwa4j5u/).

The main jquery engine is here:

```
        var quizSteps = $('#quizzie .quiz-step'),
            //highScoreVariable = 9,
            categoryOneScore = 0,
            categoryTwoScore = 0,
            categoryThreeScore = 0;
        quizSteps.each(function () {
            var currentStep = $(this),

                ansOpts = currentStep.children('.quiz-answer');


            ansOpts.each(function () {
                var eachOpt = $(this);
                //var eachOpt = document.getElementById('submit');
                eachOpt[0].addEventListener('click', check, false);
                //document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', check, false);

                function check() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var cat1Answer = $this.attr('data-quizIndexCat1');
                    if (typeof cat1Answer !== typeof undefined && cat1Answer !== false) {
                        categoryOneScore += parseInt(cat1Answer);
                        //alert('P' + categoryOneScore);
                    }
                    var cat2Answer = $this.attr('data-quizIndexCat2');
                    if (typeof cat2Answer !== typeof undefined && cat2Answer !== false) {
                        categoryTwoScore += parseInt(cat2Answer);
                       // alert('B' + categoryTwoScore);
                    }
                    var cat3Answer = $this.attr('data-quizIndexCat3');
                    if (typeof cat3Answer !== typeof undefined && cat3Answer !== false) {
                        categoryThreeScore += parseInt(cat3Answer);
                       // alert('D' + categoryThreeScore);
                    }
                    $this.addClass('active');
                    $('current').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
                    calcResults();
                    updateStep(currentStep);
                }
            });

            function updateStep(currentStep) {
                if (currentStep.hasClass('current')) {
                    //currentStep.removeClass('current').fadeTo("slow");
                    currentStep.slideUp(500, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('current');
                    });
                    //currentStep.removeClass('current');
                    currentStep.next().slideDown(500, function() {
                    $(this).addClass('current');
                    });
                    //currentStep.next().addClass('current');
                    //alert (quizSteps);
                    window.console.log(quizSteps);
                }
            }
            function calcResults() {
                // only update the results div if all questions have been answered
                if (quizSteps.find('.active').length == quizSteps.length) {
                    window.console.log(" Procrastinator score is =" + categoryOneScore);
                    window.console.log("Busy Bee score is =" + categoryTwoScore);
                    window.console.log("Distracted score is =" + categoryThreeScore);
                    //alert (quizSteps);

                    var msgIndex = 0;
                    if ((categoryOneScore == 3 &&
                            categoryOneScore == categoryThreeScore  &&
                            categoryOneScore == categoryTwoScore) ) {
                        msgIndex = 7;

                    }
                    else if ((categoryOneScore == categoryTwoScore &&
                            categoryTwoScore == categoryThreeScore) ) {
                        msgIndex = 3;

                    } 
                    else if ((categoryOneScore == categoryTwoScore &&
                            categoryTwoScore > categoryThreeScore) ) {
                        msgIndex = 4;
                        //alert ('Case 2');

                    }
                    else if ((categoryOneScore == categoryThreeScore &&
                            categoryThreeScore > categoryTwoScore) ) {
                        msgIndex = 5;

                    }
                    else if ((categoryTwoScore == categoryThreeScore &&
                            categoryThreeScore > categoryOneScore) ) {
                        msgIndex = 6;

                    }
                    else if ((categoryOneScore >= categoryTwoScore &&
                        categoryOneScore >= categoryThreeScore) ) {
                        msgIndex = 0;

                    }
                    else if ((categoryTwoScore >= categoryOneScore &&
                            categoryTwoScore >= categoryThreeScore) ) {
                        msgIndex = 1;

                    }  
                    else if ((categoryThreeScore >= categoryOneScore &&
                            categoryThreeScore >= categoryTwoScore) ) {
                        msgIndex = 2;
                    }  

                    var resultsTitle = $('#results h1'),
                        resultsDesc = $('#results .desc');
                    resultsTitle.replaceWith("<h1>" + resultOptions[msgIndex].title + "</h1>");
                    resultsDesc.replaceWith("<p class='desc'>" + resultOptions[msgIndex].desc + "</p>");
                    window.CP.exitedLoop(6);
                    //document.getElementById("instrct").style.opacity="0";
                    //alert(msgIndex);

                }
            }

        });
```

I guess I am just looking for some idea of how to call the function currently being called by clicking on the answer by clicking a submit button instead.

Comment: Please also provide a fiddle with your conversion attempt. You need to capture the selection (convert to checkboxes or just save the value to a variable, maybe) and then basically do what you're doing now. The question is too broad without some initial effort shown.

Comment: From a UX point of view, if all the questions were on one page, then use a submit button would be ideal.  As it looks like you want a submit per question, that's horrendous UX and I, personally, would be annoyed by the 3rd question and give up.

Comment: I can see that, but unfortunately the client has different ideas, and they are looking for a 'Buzzfeed style' quiz.

Answer (score 1):

`updateStep` is "private" to `ansOpt.each` so you can't call it from a submit button.  You need to move/expose that function to where it can be called, then you can call it using the current active question.

In the simplest terms:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  updateStep($(".current"))
});

function updateStep(currentStep) {
```

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sph42onb/1/

I would probably make a few other changes such as namespacing the above function (as it's now exposed) and using a more specific class name than `.current` which could *possibly* be used elsewhere on your page.

Comment: That actually is the information I was looking for, thanks so much!

Comment: For some reason it is throwing this error now at the end: 

>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exitedLoop' of undefined
    at calcResults (quiz_wSubmit.html:514)
    at HTMLLIElement.check (quiz_wSubmit.html:459)

Comment: Yes, I spotted that, but it didn't appear to be directly related to the question.  Perhaps ask a new question?